# How to return current user's booking history in django rest framework?

Tags: python, django, api, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have created a booking api where user have to login to book a package ( holiday package). Now how can a user after login check their booking history that means the bookings that they made? That means I want to create an api where if a user clicks my bookings, it will return the bookings that the user has made.

My booking model:

```
class Booking(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    package = models.ForeignKey(Package, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='package')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email = models.EmailField()
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    bookedfor = models.DateField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Package(models.Model):
    destination = models.ForeignKey(Destination, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    package_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    featured = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    duration = models.IntegerField(default=5)
    discount = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="15% OFF")
    discounted_price = models.IntegerField(default=230)
    savings = models.IntegerField(default=230)
    special_discount = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

My booking serializer:

```
class BookingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # blog = serializers.StringRelatedField()
    class Meta:
        model = Booking
        fields = ['name', 'email', 'phone', 'bookedfor']
        # fields = '__all__'
```

My booking view:

```
class BookingCreateAPIView(CreateAPIView):
    permission_classes= [IsAuthenticated]
    queryset = Booking.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BookingSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        # user = self.request.user
        package = get_object_or_404(Package, pk= self.kwargs['pk'])
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user,package=package)
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have to add a new url at your urls.py file.
After that in the classs BookingCreateAPIView you should create a new method to display all the Bookings made by the user.
The method could be:

```
def perform_query(self):
    bookings = Booking.objects.get(user=request.user)
    return HttpResponse(bookings)
```

Comment: def get(self, request):
        bookings = Booking.objects.get(user=request.user)
        return HttpResponse(bookings)                                    I used this but it only returns a single object, raise an error when there are multiple bookings booked by a single user.

Answer (score 0):

You can use for get the user in views.py orders like :-

```
from .models import Booking

def BookingCreateAPIView(CreateAPIView):
    orders = Booking.objects.get(user=request.user)
```

Comment: def get(self, request):                                                                                                     bookings = Booking.objects.get(user=request.user)                                                 
 return HttpResponse(bookings) I used this but it only returns a single object, raise an error when there are multiple bookings booked by a single user.

Answer (score 0):

Then Try this :-

```
def BookingCreateAPIView(CreateAPIView):
        bookings = Booking.objects.order_by('created_at')
        bookings = Booking.objects.filter(owner=request.user).order_by('created_at')
```

Comment: Thanks!, It worked but it should be user instead of owner

Comment: Oh yeah ! Your Welcome Saroj .